# Spark Streaming: HDFS

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming

1. I can't get my Spark job to stream "old" files from HDFS.

If my Spark job is down for some reason (e.g. demo, deployment) but the writing/moving to HDFS directory is continuous, I might skip those files once I up the Spark Streaming Job.

```
    val hdfsDStream = ssc.textFileStream("hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com/user/root/logs")

    hdfsDStream.foreachRDD(
      rdd => logInfo("Number of records in this batch: " + rdd.count())
    )
```

Output --> Number of records in this batch: 0

2. Is there a way for Spark Streaming to move the "read" files to a different folder? Or we have to program it manually? So it will avoid reading already "read" files.
3. Is Spark Streaming the same as running the spark job (sc.textFile) in CRON?

Answer (score 7):

As Dean mentioned, textFileStream uses the default of only using new files.

```
  def textFileStream(directory: String): DStream[String] = {
    fileStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat](directory).map(_._2.toString)
  }
```

So, all it is doing is calling this variant of `fileStream`

```
def fileStream[
    K: ClassTag,
    V: ClassTag,
    F <: NewInputFormat[K, V]: ClassTag
  ] (directory: String): InputDStream[(K, V)] = {
    new FileInputDStream[K, V, F](this, directory)
  }
```

And, looking at the `FileInputDStream` class we will see that it indeed can look for existing files, but defaults to new only:

```
newFilesOnly: Boolean = true,
```

So, going back into the `StreamingContext` code, we can see that there is and overload we can use by directly calling the `fileStream` method:

```
def fileStream[
 K: ClassTag,
 V: ClassTag,
 F <: NewInputFormat[K, V]: ClassTag] 
(directory: String, filter: Path => Boolean, newFilesOnly: Boolean):InputDStream[(K, V)] = {
  new FileInputDStream[K, V, F](this, directory, filter, newFilesOnly)
}
```

### **So, the TL;DR; is**

```
ssc.fileStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat]
    (directory, FileInputDStream.defaultFilter, false).map(_._2.toString)
```

Comment: hi Justin, thanks for this. But I am only able to read old files I placed there for the last 5 seconds before I run the Spark job. Is there a setting I need to update? This is part of the logs, I'm not sure if it has something to do with it: INFO dstream.FileInputDStream: Slide time = 10000 ms and this is my new code: val hdfsDStream = ssc.fileStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat]("hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com/user/root/logs", (t: Path) => true, newFilesOnly=false).map(_._2.toString)

Comment: @sophie I am fairly certain that this is a bug. However, digging into it...it looks like a naive fix would break a lot. The gist is that they are doing a `max` where they should be doing a `min`....but I think files may end up processing over and over if you fix just that part....I will submit the bug sometime this weekend and post it.

Comment: hi Justin, would you know if this is fixed already? I still can't get it to work.

Comment: I'm still skeptical it is exactly this issue, but https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6061

Answer (score 3):

Are you expecting Spark to read files already in the directory? If so, this is a common misconception, one that took me by surprise. `textFileStream` watches a directory for *new* files to appear, then it reads them. It ignores files already in the directory when you start or files it's already read.

The rationale is that you'll have some process writing files to HDFS, then you'll want Spark to read them. Note that these files much appear atomically, e.g., they were slowly written somewhere else, then *moved* to the watched directory. This is because HDFS doesn't properly handle reading and writing a file simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

```
val filterF = new Function[Path, Boolean] {
    def apply(x: Path): Boolean = {
      println("looking if "+x+" to be consider or not")
      val flag = if(x.toString.split("/").last.split("_").last.toLong < System.currentTimeMillis){ println("considered "+x); list += x.toString; true}
       else{ false }
      return flag
    }
}
```

this filter function is used to determine whether each path is actually the one preferred by you. so the function inside the apply should be customized as per your requirement.

```
val streamed_rdd = ssc.fileStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat]("/user/hdpprod/temp/spark_streaming_output",filterF,false).map{case (x, y) => (y.toString)}
```

now you have to set the third variable of filestream function to  false, this is to make sure not only new files but also consider old existing files in the streaming directory.

Comment: In the function filterF, list is not defined